# How can I write complex math equations on Posterous using Latex

Tags: posterous

How can I write complex math equations on [posterous](http://www.posterous.com) using [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/)? Do they support it or anything similar?

I have mailed their support two times in a row, but there was  no response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this blog post](http://blog.antoniocangiano.com/why-and-how-i-migrated-from-posterous-to-self-hosted-wordpress), Posterous is a rather inflexible blogging tool.  As far as I know, there isn't any support for what you want to do, and I do know that it would be very difficult if not impossible to do this yourself - Posterous doesn't really allow custom javascript to run on a blog, which is probably what you'd need.

If you are willing to migrate away from Posterous, then I'd suggest you add [MathJax](http://mathjax.org) to the blog to do this; it's what's used on sites like [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/) to render mathematics and works really well.

If you're not, then I think you'll need to do some pre-processing of your Posterous posts to detect LateX, render it, save it as an image, and replace the LaTeX with that image in the post.  Not really a nice way to do it, but it seems there's no other way.

Comment: I've never really encountered anything like 'Posterous is not a good choice'. But, yes it sounds like I have to switch. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What blogging platform has most feature on it? Tumblr?

Comment: I don't know, I suppose it would depend on how flexible and vibrant its plug-in system was.  It will always be a trade-off between ease of use (posterous is super-easy, just email your post in...) and flexibility (write your own blogging software and it can do whatever you want).